# void Fillcombo string issue

Tags: combobox

I'm really beginner and I'm on a middle of my first code that actually I copy from some good online course I'm taking.

this code below can't except my string

```
string Namelist = myReader.GetInt32("fname");
comboBox1.Items.Add();
```

when I'm typing this string under while I'm getting error "can't convert from string to int"

```
void Fillcombo() {

            string conn = "Data Source=srv-db-02;Initial Catalog=rmsmasterdbtest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=*******";
            string Query = "select * from rmsmasterdbtest.dbo.userlogin  ;";
            SqlConnection Myconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, Myconn);
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                Myconn.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
               while (myReader.Read())
               {
                    string namelist = myReader.GetInt32("fname");
                    comboBox1.Items.Add();           
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String nameList = String.valueOf(myReader.GetInt32("fname"));
```

Comment: also make sure you put "String" not "string"

Comment: after I tried your suggestion I'm getting this error

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'valueOf'

Comment: use String not string

Comment: As in the online course they show with the "string"

Comment: I went over all is session and I was successful to programing everything until I stack in this phase

Comment: Hi there I have found the issue here is the code I had to replece

Comment: string namelist = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("fname"));